# Determine whether we can pack $(r_1, \dots, r_k)$ copies of the variables $(A_1, \dots, A_k)$ into a string $s$, in time polynomial in $|s|$?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, time-complexity, polynomial-time, open-problem

Let $s \in \Sigma^*$ be a finite string over alphabet $\Sigma$.   Find all "compressible" substrings of $s$, that is substrings $t \leqslant s$ (notation) such that $t\alpha t \leqslant s$ for some $\alpha \leqslant s$ and $|t| \geq 2$.  It's true that with the usual size of a smallest grammar for $s$ that a length-2 string is not really compressible unless it occurs at least 3 times disjointly in $s$ i.e. $t \alpha t \beta t \leqslant s$, however, we still call it as such.  It doesn't matter because you can reduce a smallest grammar with it's length-2 twice occuring substrings and retain its same size.  Call the set of compressible substrings $C_s$.

Take $s = ababcababc$ as our example string.  Then $C_s = \{ab,ba,bc,aba,abc,bab, abab, babc, ababc\}$.  In general since there are $O(|s|^2)$ substrings we can say that $|C_s| = O(|s|^2)$ safely.

Now, assign variables to these substrings:

$$
A \to ab \\
B \to ba \\
C \to bc \\
D \to aba \\
E \to abc \\
F \to bab \\
G \to abab \\
H \to babc \\
I \to ababc \\
$$

Call the set of variables (LHS's) $V$ and the set of expaned rules (RHS's) $R$.

For a single variable $A$ it is clear to me that a left-most packing in $s$ is a sufficient tool to find the maximal number of $A$'s we can pack into $s$ via substring-to-variable substitution:

$$
s  \Rightarrow AAcAAc
$$
This in particular works if we have long runs of $a$'s : $s' = aaaaabababaabaaaaaaa \Rightarrow A'A'abababA'bA'A'A'a$ and say $A' \to aa$.  So it works for all cases.  But that's not the proof I'm worried about.

I'm wondering if there exists a polynomial-time algorithm in $|s| = N$ such that given any number $1 \leq k \leq |C_s|$, where $C_s = \{c_1, c_2, \dots c_n\}$, of variables $v_1, \dots, v_k$, we can determine if $r_1$ copies of $v_1$ can be packed into $s$, while simultaneously $r_2$ copies of $v_2$ can be packed in, ..., while simultaneously $r_k$ copies of $v_k$ can be packed in.

Can you state this in terms of a maximal (or less) independent subset of vertices of a graph algorithm, that happens to be solvable in polynomial time?

Because you take take each variable's $i$th occurence, for example $s \Rightarrow A^1A^2cA^3A^4c$ denoted with a superscript that doesn't mean concatenation powering, and label a graph with these variables $A^i$, $B^j$, and so on..   Then two variables conflict if they overlap if you try to pack them both into $s$, so draw an undirected edge between their vertices.  This I will call a "conflict graph".   Well, we're not exactly looking for a maximal independent subset, so I was wondering if this related or special case were solvable in polynomial time.

Comment: I think this might be doable with an integer-linear system and Gaussian elimination.